# JavaScript AJAX & Rails Controller (back-and-forth)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-events

I'm sending information back-and-forth between a Rails controller and a JS file.

1. I'm sending the form to the controller through JS (works)

   ```
   $("#help-email-submit").ajaxSubmit({url: '/help/send_help_email', type: 'post' });
   ```
2. I'm able to catch the event in the controller (works)

   ```
   def send_help_email
     ....
   end
   ```
3. In the same JS file that sent the above request, how do I capture the JSON response (below)? (doesn't work)

   ```
   def send_help_email
     ...
     cst_str = @current_support_ticket.to_s
     respond_to do |format|
       format.json { render :json => cst_str }
     end
   end
   ```

   In the JS file

   ```
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
   ```

---

UPDATE

I noticed a JS error that is preventing the success: function from executing:

Error

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#help-email-     form").ajaxSubmit({url: '/help/send_help_email', type: 'post', complete: handlerResponse })')

This is the line that is triggering the error

```
$("#help-email-form").ajaxSubmit({url: '/help/send_help_email', type: 'post', complete: handlerResponse })
```

This is complete block

```
var handlerResponse = function(data) {
alert(data);
};

$('#help-email-submit').live('click', function(e) {
    $('#sender-email-wrapper').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $("#help-email-sent").fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $("#help-email-form").ajaxSubmit({url: '/help/send_help_email', type: 'post', complete: handlerResponse })
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Is there some sort of stack error you can post?

Comment: What does `$.fn.ajaxSubmit` on the console give you?

Comment: `$.fn.ajaxSubmit` returns undefined

Comment: @VerdiErelErgün it seems that you don't have the plugin loaded them. Check out if it's included properly on your page with a `<script>` tag, and if it is *after* the jQuery `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`ajaxSubmit` documentation](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#api), it accepts the same options that the [`jQuery.ajax` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). So, to get the response, you can pass the `complete` callback to the call:

```js
var handleResponse = function(data) {
  // Use response here
};

$("#help-email-submit").ajaxSubmit({url: '/help/send_help_email', type: 'post', complete: handleResponse });
```

Depending on the version of jQuery that you are using, you can also pass the callback through the `complete` method on the return value from `jQuery.ajax`:

```
$("#help-email-submit").ajaxSubmit({url: '/help/send_help_email', type: 'post'}).complete(function(data) {
  // Use response here
});
```

Comment: That seems to maybe work, I'm getting a type error now, which I think is preventing the code in handlerResponse from executing (although the  post is working just fine)

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#help-email-submit").ajaxSubmit({url: '/help/send_help_email', type: 'post', complete: handlerResponse })')

Comment: The name of the function in my code is `handleResponse`, not `handlerResponse`. Check out if it matches on your code

Comment: Ahhh I noticed that and changed that. I found this information on ajaxSubmit. It looks like it's not part of jQuery core and needs some external libraries.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: Yes, I thought you were using it already, since you said that you were able to capture the event on your ruby code.

Comment: Ah shoot, I uprgraded the plugin and jquery and that still doesn't seem to have solved the problem.

Comment: This is the complete problem block:

var handlerResponse = function(data) {
   alert('hello!');
 };

$('#help-email-submit').live('click', function(e) {
  $('#sender-email-wrapper').fadeOut('fast', function() {
   $("#help-email-sent").fadeIn('slow');
  });
  $("#help-email-form").ajaxSubmit({url: '/help/send_help_email', type: 'post', complete: handlerResponse })
  e.preventDefault();
 });

Comment: What is the error it is giving to you? Still `'undefined' is not a function`? On which line it happens?

Comment: I just posted the details in an update. Thanks for your help Renato.